# How to set up windows authentication just for a single route in ASP.NET MVC on iis6?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-6, windows-authentication

I'm developing a web application and I need to mix Forms & Windows authentication together.

The approach which I selected is this: authentication method on all the web site has to be forms auth. There is a form page (`~/home/Login`) to login in via forms auth. The magic (and trouble) is that only one page (say `~/Home/WinLogin`) has to have auth metod set up to be windows auth. This page is used to read `HttpContext.User.Identity.Name` to get the windows user name.

***What I don't know is how to set up the win auth on iis6 for the one particular route?***

The route looks like `~/Home.ashx/WinLogin`. Ok, but what then? I tried to create a directory Home.ashx in the virtual directory and subdirectory WinLogin. But then `~/Home.ashx/Login` (with the login form) stopped working.

Because on iis6 we have to use a ashx handler it seems that there is no other way how to do it instead of creating a ordinary web page `~/WinLogin.aspx` that does the work. However I wanted to avoid that and use MVC only.

Just for info how to setup iis7: [IIS 7.0 Server-Side blog](http://mvolo.com/blogs/serverside/archive/2008/02/11/IIS-7.0-Two_2D00_Level-Authentication-with-Forms-Authentication-and-Windows-Authentication.aspx)
It's not perfect (Mike Volodarsky had to create custom forms auth module), but it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't selectively set windows auth in IIS6 like you can in IIS7. You could however set the home.ashx to support anonymous and windows auth; replace the HttpContext.User property in the /Login case and use the windows principle in the /WinLogin case. However, you need to be careful that your code path allows for the case where you want them to use forms auth but they're presenting you with a windows principle identity and ignore that.